# how to send SMS in Flash Air for Android

Tags: android, flash, air, sms

I am trying build an sms based application in AIR (Flash)
Got this code from an old link

```
str = "sms:1-415-555-1212"; 
var urlReq:URLReq = new URLRequest(str); 
navigateToURL(urlReq);
```

but this one is 5 years old and lot has change and even Flash is now Animate CC
so can anyone help me in this

Comment: flash not supported by android anymore

Comment: It is still does with AIR
I have made a small test to confirm the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 years, but still nothing changed - your code will work on modern devices.

You can use the URL with `sms:` - This is supported in all mobile OS:

```
private function sendSMS(phone:string):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("sms:" + phone));   
}
```

For example:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("sms:+00133234534"));
```

---

**Bonus Tip!**

Send a phone call: `navigateToURL(new URLRequest("tel:" + phone));`

Send an email: `navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:" + email));`

Comment: There is one more query, the above code composes message, so  to send on click the message on click is there a different code